# how to pick most matching string from tupled strings

Tags: c#, string, match, similarity

I have these lines of code in my program. i.e.

```
var scored = lines.Select(line => 
    Tuple.Create(line, p.calculate_CS(line, summary), summary));
dd.AddRange(scored); 
var top_value = dd.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item2).FirstOrDefault();
```

I also have to write most similar match into the database, So want to have most similar calculated value plus most similar word matched string also.

```
if (top_value.Item2 > 0 && top_value != null)
{
    var abstrct = top_value.Item3.ToString();
    var r_field = top_value.Item1.ToString();
    write_To_Database(abstrct, r_field);
}
```

Tuple has three vairables i.e. `string line` (i.e. strings to be matched 373 in number) `double similarity value` and `string summary`(i.e. single string to get matched with all 373). The item `line` is matched with item `summary`.
The variable `top_value` is the most highest similarity value between `line` and `summary` strings. 
Now the problem is the `similarity value` for `summary` becomes same for some of the strings in `line`. So the strings in `line` are sorted alphabetically. So if the highest value is same for some of the strings, the top_value will have the highest value alphabetically whereas it may be most similar with lower strings.

So I want to have most highest similar value in top_value plus also the most similar string match also regardless the alphabetically sorted order.

For example if `summary` is "Software engineering in 2001 - A case" the matched values are (given by these lines of code).

[image: Results of scoring lines and summary matches]

As it can be seen from image attached that string to be matched contains strings `Software Engineering.........` where I got `engineering design` in the highest `top_value` whereas it should be `software engineering`. The calculation of similarity value based on terms after splitting both of string to be match and the matcher string. But due to alphabetically sorted order of strings in `line`, I got `engineering design` instead of `software engineering`
Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You clearly need to change your matching algorithm if it is giving you undesired matches. Since you don't post your matching algorithm here, I'll just use my own example of how this needs to be done. I've reverse engineered your `calculate_CS` algorithm to match your results over the given input, although I'd guess it's not the same as your implementation. It's just for illustration. Also, the choice of algorithm I've used to change the match scoring is arbitrary, and may not meet your needs. It's also just for illustration.

```
void Main()
{
    var lines = new[] { 
        "engineering design",
        "requirement engineering", 
        "reverse engineering",
        "software engineering",
        "access control policies",
        "active learning", 
        "ad hock network", 
        "agent based reasoning"
        // etc...
    };

    var summary = "Software engineering in 2001 - A case";

    var dd = new List<Tuple<String, Double, String>>();
    dd.AddRange(lines.Select(line => Tuple.Create(line, calculate_CS(line, summary), summary)));
    var top_value = dd.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item2).FirstOrDefault();

    var ddNew = new List<Tuple<String, Double, String>>();
    ddNew.AddRange(lines.Select(line => Tuple.Create(line, calculate_Lcs(line, summary), summary)));
    var top_value_new = ddNew.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item2).FirstOrDefault();

    top_value.Dump();
    top_value_new.Dump();
}

private double calculate_CS(string line, string summary)
{
    var lineWords = line?.ToLower().Split(' ');
    var summaryWords = summary?.ToLower().Split(' ');

    return lineWords?.Intersect(summaryWords).Any() ?? false
        ? 0.110795817239161
        : 0;
}

private double calculate_Lcs(string line, string summary)
{  
    // using https://www.nuget.org/packages/DuoVia.FuzzyStrings/
    return line.LongestCommonSubsequence(summary).Item2;
}
```

([Download LinqPad Query](http://share.linqpad.net/2f979n.linq))

Results:

[image: Comparison of the results of applying different matching algorithms to the lines and summary input]